# Getting "parse error" when creating Gmail label

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API to create a label, using URL https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels.  Works perfectly for me.  However several customers are reporting this fails with http error 400, with the error:

> "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message": "Parse Error"

The json that is input to the call is very simple, example:

> {"name":"Secretarial Misc."}

Any idea what the problem could be?  Why would the exact same json work for me but not somebody else?

Comment: Could you show your code? It sounds like your are using ajax or something of that nature, and don't use JSON.stringify on your data.

Comment: No I am using C++ and making direct http calls using libcurl.  I generate the json by "hand".  The example I gave is exactly what is transmitted via http POST.  I'm wondering if Google misses the various CR/LF and whitespace characters.  Although that doesn't explain why it works for me - maybe different versions of Gmail software on different servers?

Comment: I see. I will post an answer you might want to try out! I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

The data you show should, according to the specification, not work for anyone. It's peculiar that is works for you! Try this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "name": "Secretarial Misc."
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Supposedly the visibility parameters are optional (I thought, since they have default values).  Possibly though the lack of CR/LF and other white space may be an issue.  I will make the change and have my customer try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  Here is the json I am submitting: {
"name":"Inbox (migrated)/2014 2015 school year info",
"messageListVisibility":"show",
"labelListVisibility":"labelShow"
}

The response I get back is: {"error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message": "Parse Error" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Parse Error" } }

Comment: @JeffMcKay Bummer! Are you sure you are passing the data as a string? I.e `'{"name": ... }'`. Sorry for sounding like a broken record, but that's what I think is still not working :) Also, don't forget to set your Content-type to `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Tholle, I was having the exact same problem and this fixed it for me!

Comment: I am using `googleapis` library for NodeJS. Send the request body after `JSON.stringify`-ing it. This ruined my 2 days. Hope this helps somebody who stumbles upon this.